# Finding the number of occurrences of each character in a String or character array

Tags: arrays, string, unicode, ascii

I am going over some interview preparation material and I was wondering what the best way to solve this problem would be if the characters in the String or array can be unicode characters. If it they were strictly ascii, you could make an `int` array of size 256 and map each ascii character to an index and that position in the array would represent the number of occurrences. If the string has unicode characters is it still possible to do so, i.e. does the unicode character a reasonable size that you could represent it using the indexes of a integer array? Since unicode characters can be more than 1 byte in size, what data type would you use to represent them? What would be the most optimal solution for this case?

Answer (score 1):

Since Unicode only defines code points in the range [0, 2<sup>21</sup>), you only need an array of 2<sup>21</sup> (i.e. 2 million) elements, which should fit comfortably into memory.

Answer (score 1):

An array wouldn't be practical when using Unicode. This is because Unicode defines (less than) 2<sup>21</sup> characters.

Instead, consider using two parallel vectors, one for the character and one for the count. The setup would look something like this:

```
<'c', '$', 'F', '¿', '¤'>    //unicode characters
< 1 ,  3 ,  1 ,  9 ,  4 >    //number of times each character has appeared.
```

*EDIT*

After seeing Kerrek's answer, I must admit, an array of size 2 million would be reasonable. The amount of memory it would take up would be in the Megabyte range.

But as it's for an interview, I wouldn't recommend having an array 2 million elements long, especially if many of those slots will be unused (not all Unicode characters will appear, most likely). They're probably looking for something a little more elegant.

*SECOND EDIT*

As per the comments here, Kerrek's answer does indeed seem to be more efficient as well as easier to code.

Comment: Could you explain why it's not practical to use an array? Wouldn't you be using just about the same amount of memory, if not more, with the vector? also, what data type do we use to represent the unicode characters in a language like Java or C. I ask because char is only 1 byte.

Comment: How do you know which index in the vector where each unicode character would map to? If you don't know this, then you have to do a linear search when you want to increment the character count.

Comment: True. We could keep the vector sorted which would make it slightly faster, but then we'd need to resort each time we encountered a new character.

I agree then. Your solution would be easier to code and most likely more efficient because of the constant lookup time for array indices.

Answer (score 0):

While others here are focusing on data structures, you should also know that the notion of "Unicode character" is somewhat ill-defined. That's a potential interview trap. Consider: are `å` and `å` the same character? The first one is a "latin small letter a with ring above" (codepoint U+00E5). The second one is a "latin small letter a" (codepoint U+0061) followed by a "combining ring above" (U+030A). Depending on the purpose of the count, you might need to consider these as the same character.

You might want to look into Unicode normalization forms. It's great fun.

Comment: It was intended as a rhetorical question. AndroidDev93 wanted to know how to respond to an hypothetical interview question about counting Unicode characters. I point out that the notion of an Unicode character is somewhat ill-defined, and that is something he should consider.

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert string to UTF-32.
2. Sort the 32-bit characters.
3. Getting character counts is now trivial.